# Checking the values of value of concated values of multiple dropdowns in VB.Net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime, drop-down-menu

I have 4 fields as:

```
    •   calStartDate = Control for the start Date Calendar (drop downs for Day, Month and Year) 
    •   ddlTime = Start time drop down
    •   calEndDate = Control for the End Date Calendar (drop downs for Day, Month and Year) 
    •   ddlTime2 = End time drop down
```

Now I have managed to save the following values in DB as;

```
•   STARTDATETIME = “2/24/2012 6:30:00 AM” 
•   ENDDATETIME = “2/24/2013 6:30:00 AM”
```

As In the following code;

```
 Dim EndDateTime As DateTime
    Dim StartDateTime As DateTime
    If chkbxAccAppBasedOnTimeInterval.Checked = True Then
       Dim StartDate As System.DateTime? = calStartDate.CurrentDate
       If StartDate.HasValue Then
          StartDateTime = StartDate.Value.AddMinutes(CType(ddlTime.SelectedValue, Double))
          EditRelTbl.STARTDATETIME = StartDateTime
       End If

       Dim EndDate As System.DateTime? = calEndDate.CurrentDate
       If EndDate.HasValue Then
          EndDateTime = EndDate.Value.AddMinutes(CType(ddlTime2.SelectedValue, Double))
          EditRelTbl.ENDDATETIME = EndDateTime
       End If

       If EndDateTime > StartDateTime Then
          DisplayAlert("End date time, must be less than Start Date and time", "Warning")
          EndDateTime = StartDateTime
       End If
Else
    EditRelTbl.STARTDATETIME = Nothing
    EditRelTbl.ENDDATETIME = Nothing
End If
```

**Issue is that I have to check that STARTDATETIME   must be greater  than ENDDATETIME    and if the End dateTime is greater than Start DateTime then the fill the End datetime as Start DateTime** as I tried to done in the code

```
If EndDateTime > StartDateTime Then
   DisplayAlert("End time must be greater than Start time", "Warning")
   EndDateTime = StartDateTime
End If
```

But this not checking the check I want. Can anyone guide me how to perform the check, or where I am mistaken.

**Note**:  ‘EditRelTbl’ is the table, where I am saving the values of End/Start date time.

Comment: I have never seen a requirement that a start date be be greater than an end date.  Date ranges are usually specified as some date in the past (say Sep 1st) as the start date, going through to some more recent date (say Dec 1st) as the end date.  In that case start is less than end.

Comment: Additionally, you test says "End time must be greater than Start time" but your code is checking the opposite, as the `EndDateTime > StartDateTime` will prompt the warning only when start is less than end. And your post also says "STARTDATETIME must be greater than ENDDATETIME".  Which are you trying to accomplish?